# QT Layouts, how to make widgets in horizontal layout move down a row instead of overflowing the window

Tags: qt, qt4

Right now I have a QHBoxLayout :

```
| W  W  W  W  W  W |
```

I resize smaller I get:

```
| W  W  W  W |
<------------>
```

I want (underlines are black space):

```
| W  W  W  W |
| W  W _ _ _ |
```

I am not sure which layout would do this. Anyone have any ideas?

The KDE Settings application does what I am looking for. I downloaded the code and have started searching but haven't found what I want yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Flow Layout Example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/layouts-flowlayout.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660080/how-does-one-fill-a-qgridlayout-from-top-left-to-right).

Comment: This works, I also used a QListWidget with icon view to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Your first link is dead

Comment: Updated the link.